# C++ DirectX11 Window Color not changing

Tags: c++, windows, directx, game-engine

I am developing a game engine using DX11. I am following a tutorial at http://www.rastertek.com/. I have done tutorial 2. The problem is that, when I try to change the color values, the window remains black. The relevant code is:

**Graphics.cpp**

```
bool Graphics::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, HWND hwnd)
{
    bool result;

    m_D3D = new D3DClass;

    if (!m_D3D)
        return false;

    result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, hwnd, VSYNC_ENABLED, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
    if (!result)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not initialize Direct3D", "Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Graphics::Render()
{
    m_D3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_D3D->EndScene();
    return true;
}
```

**D3DClass.cpp**

```
bool D3DClass::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, HWND hwnd, bool vsync, bool fullscreen, float screenDepth, float screenNear)
{
    HRESULT result;
    IDXGIFactory* factory;
    IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
    IDXGIOutput* adapterOutput;
    unsigned int numModes, i, numerator, denominator, stringLength;
    DXGI_MODE_DESC* displayModeList;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
    int error;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    float fieldOfView, screenAspect;

    m_vsync_enabled = vsync;


    result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    result = factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;


    result = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &adapterOutput);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;


    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, NULL);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;


    displayModeList = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[numModes];
    if (!displayModeList)
        return false;


    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, displayModeList);
    if(FAILED(result))
        return false;


    for (int i = 0; i < numModes; i++)
    {
        if (displayModeList[i].Height == (unsigned int)screenHeight && displayModeList[i].Width == (unsigned int)screenWidth)
        {
            numerator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Numerator;
            denominator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Denominator;
            break;
        }
    }


    result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;


    m_videoCardMemory = (int)(adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory / 1048576); //MB

    error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
    if (error != 0)
        return false;


    delete[] displayModeList;
    displayModeList = 0;

    adapterOutput->Release();
    adapterOutput = 0;

    adapter->Release();
    adapter = 0;

    factory->Release();
    factory = 0;


    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;

    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

    if (m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator;
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    }

    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

    //MultiSampling Off
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    swapChainDesc.Windowed = !fullscreen;

    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    backBufferPtr->Release();
    backBufferPtr = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

    depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
    depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    //Multisampling off
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;


    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));
    depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;


    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);

    //TODO::CUSTOMIZE USER PRESETS
    rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
    rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

    result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);
    if (FAILED(result))
        return false;

    m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

    viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
    viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    //TODO:: FOV SETTINGS
    fieldOfView = (float)D3DX_PI / 4.0f;
    screenAspect = (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight;

    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&m_projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, screenAspect, screenNear, screenDepth);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&m_worldMatrix);
    D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&m_orthoMatrix, (float)screenWidth, (float)screenHeight, screenNear, screenDepth);

    return true;
}
void D3DClass::BeginScene(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{

    m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, D3DXCOLOR(red, green, blue, alpha));

    m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
    return;
}

void D3DClass::EndScene()
{
    if (m_vsync_enabled)
        m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
    else
        m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);

    return;
}
```

**Framework.cpp**

```
void Framework::InitializeWindows(int& screenWidth, int& screenHeight)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;

    int posX, posY;

    m_application = this;
    m_hinstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    m_applicationName = "Racing Game";

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = m_hinstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = wc.hIcon;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = m_applicationName;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    if (FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = (unsigned long)screenWidth;
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = (unsigned long)screenHeight;
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);

        posX = posY = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        screenWidth = 800;
        screenHeight = 600;

        posX = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - screenWidth) / 2;
        posY = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - screenHeight) / 2;
    }

    m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, m_applicationName, m_applicationName, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP, posX, posY, screenWidth, screenHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(m_hwnd);
    SetFocus(m_hwnd);

    ShowCursor(false);
    return;
}
```

Each time I change the parameters in the`BeginScene()` call, no matter what those are (i tried values ranging from 1.0f to 256.0f on the red), the window is always black and there isn't the windows top three buttons (close, minimize, expand). What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The Rastertek tutorials still work, but they use a lot of legacy stuff so keep that in mind. You might want to look at the tutorial for [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following the same tutorials,

It's floating point value between 0 and 1.

so in your case for red color it's

```
bool Graphics::Render()
{
    m_D3D->BeginScene(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_D3D->EndScene();
    return true;
}
```

Don't forget to set opacity to 1.0 the last value.

Good luck for the next ones.